# Vim removes newline characters when I paste

Tags: vim

I'm using my mouse to select a multi-line section of text in one vim terminal window, and paste it into another vim terminal window. When I paste, everything is pasted onto a single line with the correct tabbing, but for some reason the newline characters are not included.

So copying this:
[code screenshot before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9tLN.png)

Results in this:
[code screenshot after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTj9Q.png)

I'm using the Ubuntu subsystem terminal on Windows 10. I'm copying from one terminal window and pasting into another.

I've tried the :set paste / :set nopaste and it seems to have no effect.
I've tried changing file format with :set ff=unix / dos and it seems to have no effect.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Some quick tests: (a) if you paste from the source window into another graphical editor, do you get the newlines stripped? (b) if you paste from a graphical editor to the destination window, do you get the newlines stripped?

Comment: Also just a hunch, but I noticed that you're getting visible lines on the same file line in the destination window, as if you're pasting carriage returns but not newlines. I wonder if there's a LF vs CRLF issue going on. Are there any interesting differences if you view the hidden characters?

Comment: [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25311/how-to-activate-bracketed-paste-mode-in-gnome-terminal-for-vim) on vi.stackexchange should put you on the right path (I'm not sure what kind of terminal windows provides).

Comment: @DavidBodow Good call - I copied from the source terminal and pasted into Notepad, and got the same result - everything on one line. Interestingly, I happened to try this with the line numbers on in the source terminal, and that pastes on separate lines as I would expect.

I also tried pasting from notepad to the terminal window, and that pasted on separate lines.